# How to use Jsoup to login my university website?

Tags: java, http, cookies, jsoup

I am trying to come up with a Android app that needs some information on the university inner website. I have been trying to use Jsoup to login the website programmatically. Here is the code I have now:

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
//import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
//import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect(
                            "https://sso.bris.ac.uk/sso/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.bris.ac.uk%2FTeaching%2Fsecure%2Funit-list.jsp%3Flist%3Dmine")
                    .execute();
            Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
            System.out.println(cookies.keySet());
            Document fakepage = res.parse();
            Element fakelt = fakepage.select("input[name=lt]").get(0);
            Element fakeexecution = fakepage.select("input[name=execution]")
                    .get(0);
            Element fake_eventID = fakepage.select("input[name=_eventId]").get(
                    0);
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
            System.out.println(fakelt.attr("value"));
            System.out.println(fakeexecution.toString());
            System.out.println(fake_eventID.toString());
//          System.out.println(cookies.get("JSESSIONID"));
            String url="https://sso.bris.ac.uk/sso/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.bris.ac.uk%2FTeaching%2Fsecure%2Funit-list.jsp%3Flist%3Dmine";
            System.out.println(url);
            Connection newreq = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .cookies(cookies).data("lt", fakelt.attr("value")).followRedirects(true).header("Connection", "keep-alive")
                    .header("Refer", " https://sso.bris.ac.uk/sso/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.bris.ac.uk%2FTeaching%2Fsecure%2Funit-list.jsp%3Flist%3Dmine")
                    .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0")
                    .data("lt",fakelt.attr("value"))
                    .data("execution", fakeexecution.attr("value"))
                    .data("_eventID", fake_eventID.attr("value"))
                    .data("username", "aabbcc").data("password", "ddeeff")
                    .data("submit", "").method(Method.POST);
            Connection.Response newres = newreq.execute();
            doc = newres.parse();
            System.out.println(doc.toString());
            System.out.println(newres.statusCode());


        Map<String,String> newcookies = newres.cookies();
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Teaching/secure/unit-list.jsp?list=mine").cookies(newcookies).get();
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
//          System.out.println(doc.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Excepiton:");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I completely faked a form to submit use Jsoup, and to get around the security cookies I first request the website once and then use the cookies it sent me to request the website again. The form has some hidden fields so I use the ones I got on my first request to fake it when I request it again. However this does not work. Is it possible to do it or the server has some advanced preventer against me doing so?

Comment: I don't see it that way because first I have the credentials needed to access the website, only I want to access it without using a browser. Second the aim of I do this is to help to create an app that make the website more accessible, not to make it corrupt or steal information. Third this is not a hack hack, this merely serve as a work around. I can raise a ticket and wait the IT people to create an API for us to use but it will take much longer. This is not for malicious purpose.

Comment: I apologize and retract my -1 vote.

Comment: I just want to say thanks for your understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Jsoup to do this, it needs you to handle all the cookies yourself, instead, use Httpclient, if you use something from 4.0 onward it handle the cookies automatically. Much eaiser to work with.